# Не понимаю что не так

Tags: c, строки, ввод

Вот этот код должен останавливать ввод строки, когда на конце будет точка, но почему-то он этого делать не хочет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    char ch[1000];
    while (ch[strlen(ch) - 1] != ".")
    {
        scanf("%s", ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, как минимум, `'.'`... В одинарных кавычках.

Comment: А что *он хочет* делать?

Comment: При вводе лучше замените `while (...) scanf(...);` на `do { scanf(...); } while (...);` / Да и результат scanf тоже надо обработать

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что оно у вас вообще скомпилировалось...

```
ch[strlen(ch) - 1] != "."
```

вы пытаетесь сравнить символ с адресом строки `"."`. Символ в C заключается в одинарные кавычки.

```
ch[strlen(ch) - 1] != '.'
```

Вот, [смотрите](https://ideone.com/wSznik)...

Да, на всякий случай - вы в курсе, что `%s` считывает не всю строку, а одно слово?..

И еще - изначально у вас строка `ch` не инициализирована - а вдруг получится так, что в ней будет эта самая точка? :) Напишите уж лучше

```
char ch[1000] = "";
```